# Error in my code first approach i have EF 4.1 with VS 2010

Tags: razor, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

**1) i have Enttiy Class In which have  three tables whose code is below given**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GridWithInlineEdit.Models
{
    #region ENTITY BLOCK
    [Table("TBLUSER", Schema = "orient")]
    public  class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            UsersDetailCollection = new List<Usersdetail>();
        }
        //
        [Key, Column("UID", TypeName = "INT")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Uid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter {0} Upto 50 Characters!")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed here!")]
        [Column("FNAME", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        public string Fname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter {0} Upto 50 Characters!")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed here!")]
        [Column("LNAME", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        public string Lname { get; set; }



        public ICollection<Usersdetail> UsersDetailCollection { get; set; }

    }

    [Table("TBLUSERDETAIL", Schema = "orient")]
    public  class Usersdetail
    {
        public Usersdetail()
        {
            CountryCollection = new List<Countries>();
        }
        [Key, Column("ID", TypeName = "INT")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }


        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column("EMAIL", TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(11)]
        [Column("PHONE", TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        public String Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId"), Column("UID", TypeName = "INT")]
        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CountryId"), Column("CID", TypeName = "INT")]
        public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }




        public ICollection<Countries> CountryCollection { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("TBLCOUNTRY", Schema = "orient")]
    public class Countries
    {
        [Key, Column("CID", TypeName = "INT")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Cid { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed here!")]
        [Column("CNAME", TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        public String Cname { get; set; }

    }
    #endregion



    #region ENTITY MAPPING BLOCK
    public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        internal UserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.Uid);
            Property(p => p.Uid).HasColumnName("UID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
            // Table & Column Mappings
            ToTable("TBLUSER");
            Property(t => t.Fname).HasColumnName("FNAME").HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(t => t.Lname).HasColumnName("LNAME").HasMaxLength(50);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class UserDetailMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usersdetail>
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        internal UserDetailMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.ID);
            HasKey(t => t.UserId);
            HasKey(t => t.CountryId);

            // Properties
            Property(t => t.Email).HasMaxLength(100);
            Property(t => t.Phone).HasMaxLength(11);

            // Column Mappings
            ToTable("TBLUSERDETAIL");
            Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
            Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("EMAIL");
            Property(t => t.Phone).HasColumnName("PHONE");
            Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UID");
            Property(t => t.CountryId).HasColumnName("CID");

            // Relationships
            HasOptional(t => t.Users).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            HasOptional(t => t.Countries).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryId);
        }

        #endregion
    }


    public class CountryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Countries>
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors
        internal CountryMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            HasKey(t => t.Cid);
            // Properties
            Property(t => t.Cname).HasMaxLength(50);
            // Column Mappings
            Property(t => t.Cid).HasColumnName("CID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
            Property(t => t.Cname).HasColumnName("CNAME");
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

}
```

**2) Second is Init Class in which have connection string custom with sqlserver 2005**

**Connection string class code is below given**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace GridWithInlineEdit.Models
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return GetDecryptedConnectionString(); }
        }

        private static string GetDecryptedConnectionString()
        {
            return @"Data Source=193.193.193.254;Initial Catalog=EFCFUsersdb;;USER ID=sa;PASSWORD=123;Persist Security Info=True";
        }
    }

    class EncryptedIDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
    {
        #region Private Fields

        IDbConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public EncryptedIDbConnectionFactory(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
        {
            if (dbConnectionFactory == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dbConnectionFactory can not be null");
            }

            _connectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDbConnectionFactory implementation
        public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            //decryption of connection string
            string decryptedConnectionString =
                GetDecryptedConnectionString(nameOrConnectionString);

            return _connectionFactory.CreateConnection(decryptedConnectionString);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private string GetDecryptedConnectionString(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            //use some encryption library to decrypt
            return nameOrConnectionString;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**and Init class is below given**

```
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace GridWithInlineEdit.Models
{
    public class Init : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SampleContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SampleContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            //context.Locations.Add(new Location() { LocationName = "Khanna, LDH" });
            //context.Sessions.Add(new Session() { SessionName = "Entity Framework" });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**3 ) this is samplecontext class code**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GridWithInlineEdit.Models
{
    public class SampleContext : DbContext
    {

        public SampleContext()
            : base(new SqlConnection(Constants.ConnectionString) ,false)
            //Data Source=193.193.193.254;Initial Catalog=EFCFUsersdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
        public DbSet<Users> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Usersdetail> UserDetail { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Countries> Country { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserDetailMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CountryMap());

        }




    }
}
```

**4) in Global file of application have  below code**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using GridWithInlineEdit.Models;

namespace GridWithInlineEdit
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
        protected void Application_Start()
        {

            //Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new EncryptedIDbConnectionFactory(Database.DefaultConnectionFactory);
            Database.SetInitializer<SampleContext>(new Init());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }

}
```

**In My Home Controller have below given code**

```
> 1. using System.Web.Mvc; using GridWithInlineEdit.Models;
>     
>     namespace GridWithInlineEdit.Controllers {
>         public class UserController : Controller
>         {
>     
>     
>             public ActionResult Index()
>             {
>                 var db = new SampleContext();
>                 return View();
>             }
>     
>             [HttpPost]
>             public ActionResult Create()
>             {
>                 
>                 //return View();
>                 return null;
>             }
>     
>         } }
```

**Now the problem is this whenever run my application database is not created and show exception server version property when i see through add watch in _db object by putting breakpoint on index action result.
pls pls resolve or give solution i have tried for this many time but i am confused why this happening**

Comment: Code first on SQL Server 2005 is trickier to get right than it is for newer SQL Server versions. Any particular reason for that version?

Comment: what's your config for EF? did you try removing the custom connection thing - and just let it create default db, or use different provider etc.

Comment: @NSGaga i have done every effort but got no any result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i am getting connection closed exception when i try to see my db object in index action result.

Comment: @NSGaga  i just want on my custom server with custom database name my database creation with ef code first.

Comment: yo man i got solution of mine problem actually i need to install a plugin whose link is below given and now my nuget package also working smartly every thing.now my database is also creating and modifying successfully.

Comment: Installation plugin name was WindowsServer2003-KB968930-x86-ENG

Answer (score 0):

I know you have in the comments above that you applied a Windows Server patch and got it working, but with looking at your project, I had some observations:

- There is nothing in your "Create" method in your controller for adding
  new records
- There is no "Read" method for returning data to anything
  that might want to read data, such as a Kendo grid.
- There is no "Delete" method for removing data records.
- I'm not sure what the UserMap, DetailMap, and CountryMap are used for, along with your "RegisterRoutes", etc. on Application_Start -- these seem like a severe case of overcomplicating things, to me.
- No View (presentation layer) code posted.

Maybe you fixed the Create, Read, and Delete routines later when you got it working, and maybe the UserMap, DetailMap, CountryMap, and Init all were for something, but be damned if I could make heads-or-tails of what you were doing.  I saw no View code, grid or otherwise, that you were pulling your data into.  When asking for help, just saying, context is everything.

While you would need to obtain and install Telerik's Kendo UI MVC components, it might be worth it to you to look at this blog for setting up the entity framework in MVC and preparing a grid for receiving data:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding